# extends Super in com.github.nscala_time.time.DurationBuilder

Tags: eclipse, scala, nscala-time

I recently downloaded source code of com.github.nscala_time package version 2.11,
After set up dependency in Maven, I got lots of errors, I checked one file
com.github.nscala_time.time.DurationBuilder, it got a line like:

```
class DurationBuilder(val underlying: Period) extends Super {..
```

There are no class or type named "Super" in the same package or imported packages. I am wondering scala has a type called "Super"? the Eclipse scala 2.11 compiler complains about cannot find type "Super"

Answer (score 1):

I think you should find it in the object time in package com.github.nscala_time. Try to add this import:

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Super
```

Comment: it complains Super is not a member of package com.github.nscala_time.time

Answer (score -1):

the solution I have is to add a trait named "Super"        `package com.github.nscala_time.time

trait Super {

}`

It seems to me the author of the library forgot to upload the class file

Comment: I got lots of help from this forum and appreciate those that help. but it seems there are people who wonder around taking delight in criticizing others. Why downvote a legitimate question and a fix for that?! Just hope it help others in a similar situation.